# nested loops causing unwanted duplicate list entries in python

Tags: python, json, api, for-loop, dictionary

My little program uses the Riot API (game), where I put players into either the 'ally team' or the 'enemy team'. Since the data comes from JSON, there are lots of lists and dicts are involved, and my issues probably stems from there, though I have not been able to find out where.

Here is the part that causes the issue:

```
first_game_test = game_list[0]
summ_team_ID = first_game_test["teamId"]
summoners_in_game = first_game_test["fellowPlayers"]
ally_team = []
enemy_team = []
for i in range(len(summoners_in_game)):
    for name, value in summoners_in_game[i].iteritems():
        if summoners_in_game[i]["teamId"] == summ_team_ID:
            #if summoners_in_game[i] not in ally_team:
                summoner_name = idtosummoner.idToSummonerName(summoners_in_game[i]['summonerId'])
                summoner_champ = champion_id.champIdGet(summoners_in_game[i]['championId'])
                ally_team.append({summoner_name: summoner_champ})
        else:
            #if summoners_in_game[i] not in enemy_team:
                enemy_team.append(summoners_in_game[i])
```

The `idtosummoner` and `champion_id` modules have been checked multiple times; I'm quite certain that the issue does not stem from there.
As you can see, I used a simple duplicate check fix (commented out). It started to mess with further coding, however: the `summoner_name`, and `summoner_champ` variables cause an error at the 3th or 4th index (I haven't added the lines to `else` yet, since I want to fix the issue first).

The console output shows the following:

```
PS C:\Users\ptnfolder> python matchhistory.py
Nussen
Nussen
Nussen
kimbb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matchhistory.py", line 67, in <module>
    matchHistory("thebirdistheword")
  File "matchhistory.py", line 39, in matchHistory
    print idtosummoner.idToSummonerName(summoners_in_game[i].get('summonerId'))
  File "C:\Users\ptnfolder\idtosummoner.py", line 10, in idToSummonerName
    champ_name_dict = json_data[str(summID)]
KeyError: '29716673'
```

The strange part is that the `KeyError` actually should resolve to `'kimbb'` - since the for loop somehow triples every entry -; it works once, and then the program crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over the *keys and values* of the dictionaries in a list:

```
for i in range(len(summoners_in_game)):
    for name, value in summoners_in_game[i].iteritems():
```

so for each key-value pair, you execute your loop body. In your loop body, you test a *specific* key:

```
if summoners_in_game[i]["teamId"] == summ_team_ID:
```

so for each key in the dictionary, you test if the value for the `'teamId'` key matches `summ_team_ID`.

This executes *as many times as there are keys in the dictionary*, but you only want to test **one** of the keys.

Just remove the loop over the key-value pairs:

```
for i in range(len(summoners_in_game)):
    if summoners_in_game[i]["teamId"] == summ_team_ID:
        summoner_name = idtosummoner.idToSummonerName(summoners_in_game[i]['summonerId'])
        summoner_champ = champion_id.champIdGet(summoners_in_game[i]['championId'])
        ally_team.append({summoner_name: summoner_champ})
    else:
        enemy_team.append(summoners_in_game[i])
```

Rather than use indices generated by `range()`, you could just loop over the list *directly*, and not have to keep indexing:

```
for team in summoners_in_game:
    if team["teamId"] == summ_team_ID:
        summoner_name = idtosummoner.idToSummonerName(team['summonerId'])
        summoner_champ = champion_id.champIdGet(team['championId'])
        ally_team.append({summoner_name: summoner_champ})
    else:
        enemy_team.append(team)
```

Comment: I see! I thought it was necessary to loop inside the loop in order to access a nested dictionary. It works perfectly now, thank you very much!